# SO Chat help pages - outdated access information

Tags: support, chat, help-center, footer

as stated in the title, some information regarding chat in the help pages ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat))

has the part about access, either partialy, either completely outdated.

Details :

- footer part : outdated
- switch menu in top-left corner : does not seems to concern SO
  [image]
  [image]
  [image]

Comment: SO is now in trouble due to their footer re-design. On Stack Overflow the link is gone ... on all other sites it isn't. So if they adapt it it needs to be a per site change. Not sure if that happens in 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. You are saying that this just concerns SO, right ? Removal of the incriminated part should not be problematic I suppose, should it ?

Comment: Yes, it concerns SO but I always forget if all help center content can be customized per site which is relevant for superuser.com and serverfault.com and the 170 other sites.

Comment: The fact that the second "circle" is not perfectly closed bothers me a lot more than it should.

Comment: @Mena that's because it is an opened ring, by design.

Comment: I noticed that the other day and wondered if it was a sign chat is going to be deprecated.

Comment: Love the edit. I can sleep at night now. Thanks.