# Misleading directions in "participate in meta" and "talk in chat" help pages

Tags: bug, help-center

Probably, problem due to new design?

[participate in meta](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta) page says:

> There is a link to meta in the footer of every page. The link also appears in the Stack Exchange site switcher (top left in the header) and under the "help" menu (top right in the header).

[talk in chat](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat) page says:

> There is a link to chat in the footer of every page, as well as in the Stack Exchange site switcher menu (top left corner of the page).

Stack Exchange site switcher is located in the top **right** corner.
Also, I can't find links in the footer.

Comment: partly duplicate: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356531/so-chat-help-pages-outdated-access-information

Answer (score -3):

Totally agree with your remark [sui-dream.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/8513105/sui-dream)

Where is meta?

There is a link to meta in the footer of every page.(edit: nope.) The link also appears in the Stack Exchange site switcher (top left in the header) and under the "help" menu (top right in the header).

Via: [stackoverflow.com/help/stackexchange](https://stackoverflow.com/help/stackexchange)

you find the first information about meta at: [stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)